# How to get max stop_date from a self joined table

Tags: mysql, sql-server, join, max

Max function is taking long time while self joining a table inside a stored procedure.

Please suggest other efficient ways to do this.

Query

```
Select a.*,b.* from acct a join acct b
On a.acctno=b.acctno
Join finance c
On a.acctno=c.acctno
Where a.insertdate between start_date and end_date
And b.stop_date=(select max(stop_date) from acct where acctno=b.acctno and addr_code=b.addr_code and unique_id<>a.unique_id and stop_date<=end_date)
```

Comment: Have you set indexes on DB?

Comment: There are no indexes on stop_date and I'm not supposed to add an index on thay column. I'm using sql management studio 2012

Comment: why do you need to joint acct to itself?  Is that a one-to-one or many-to-many join?  If it is one-to-one then you are just looking at the same record, if it is many to many then you are creating a cross joined matrix of acct records

Comment: It is one to many join and need to join like this only to get different country code values of a single account

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However, add explanation of code and description so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Use this, Hope it will help.

```
Select a.*,b.* from acct a,acct b,finance c
where a.acctno=b.acctno
and a.acctno=c.acctno
and a.insertdate 
between a.start_date and a.end_date
And b.stop_date=(select max(stop_date) from acct a,acct b 
where a.acctno=b.acctno 
and a.addr_code=b.addr_code 
and a.unique_id<>b.unique_id 
and a.stop_date<=a.end_date)
```